# Use commaseparated mySQL column value in LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have column in my database named as `foodtype` . Table name is restaurant and the column `foodtype` has comma separated values (as Indian,Chinese).

Now, when a person select Chinese then the i want mysql query should return restaurant where `foodtype` is Chinese.

Query should become like as below:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cityname='Chicago' and foodtype 
LIKE ('%Chinese%')
```

And when a person select Indian then the i want mysql query should return restaurant where foodtype is Indian.

Query should become like as below:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cityname='Chicago' and foodtype 
LIKE ('%Indian%')
```

And when a person select Indian and Chinese both then the i want mysql query should return restaurant where foodtype is Indian and Chinese.

Query should become like as below:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE cityname='Chicago' and foodtype 
LIKE ('%Indian%,%Chinese%')
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Comment: Really you should fix your database design instead. Use another table to store the foodtypes are query the thing using a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurant 
WHERE cityname='Chicago' 
and find_in_set(foodtype, 'Indian') > 0
and find_in_set(foodtype, 'Chinese') > 0
```

But actually you are better off by chaning your table structure. Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

To achieve that you can add 2 other tables to your DB

```
foodtypes table
---------------
id
name


restaurant_foodtypes
--------------------
restaurant_id
foodtype_id
```

Example data:

```
foodtypes
id   |  name
1    |  chinese
2    |  indian

restaurant_foodtypes
restanrant_id  |  foodtype_id
1              |  1
1              |  2
```

Then you can select restaurants having both foodtypes like this

```
select r.name
from restaurants r
join restaurant_foodtypes rf on rf.restaurant_id = r.id
join foodtypes f on rf.foodtype_id = f.id
where f.name in ('indian','chinese')
group by r.name
having count(distinct f.name) = 2
```

Comment: will `FIND_IN_SET()`  not slow down search query ?

Comment: Can u please let me know that how can i store multiple foodtype values against one restaurant?

Comment: Not more than using `LIKE '%' which can't make use of indexes. That is why you should change your table structure